# Is it dangerous that request.user is exposing user' s password?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to DRF and django. I noticed that request.user.password is exposing logged in user password (hashed) and I thought that this might be dangerous.

Can a third party have access to request?

I create a serializer that exclude password.
I tried to write a middleware for this and i have this message when a user log in :

> rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: 'ReturnDict' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Middleware.py

```
from users.serializers import RequestUserSerializer


def RemovePasswordFromUser(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        if request.user.id is not None:
            request.user = RequestUserSerializer(request.user).data
            print(request.user)
        response = get_response(request)
        return response

    return middleware
```

RequestUserSerializer.py

```
class RequestUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        exclude = ["password"]
```

Log In Class in views.py

```
class LoginAPI(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data["username"]
        password = request.data["password"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is None:
            return Response(
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, data={"message": "Wrong Crendentials"}
            )
        login(request, user)
        request.user = RequestUserSerializer(request.user).data
        print(type(request.user))
        return Response(
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            data={"message": "User Login"},
        )
```

i tried to write a middleware for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by the third party here.

If you mean some library under the hood that you use in the context of Django - yes the library could technically access `user.password` if you pass `request` inside.
But in the same way we could say that django framework source code could be malicious and use our users' passwords without us knowing.

TLDR - this is fine that inside your Django application runtime, you can access `request.user.password`. When you access it, you can see it is hashed too by default.

On whether you want to expose it through the API in response - you definitely don't.
To do so, you just don't include your `password` field in the serializer and later on, it is not included in the response body. (in your case you excluded it).

> I create a serializer that exclude password. I tried to write a middleware for this and i have this message when a user log in :

> rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: 'ReturnDict' object has no attribute 'is_active'

It happens because `RequestUserSerializer(request.user).data` returns a dictionary and not a `User` object.
But again, if idea of this middleware was to just hide the `password` field on the user object, most certainly you don't need to do it.